snap-store fails to execute in Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Similar to this and this
I have just performed an upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 to 22.04 and noticed that snap-store will not load. Running it from the command line returns the following error:
/snap/snap-store/1113/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-software/libgnomesoftware.so.16: undefined symbol: g_task_set_static_name

/var/log/syslog has the following entries:
Sep  4 16:54:54 ubuntu systemd[1910]: Started Application launched by gnome-shell.
Sep  4 16:54:54 ubuntu systemd[1910]: Started snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software-7ad9e8e9-cb46-486b-985a-cd5fff83032b.scope.
Sep  4 16:54:54 ubuntu snap-store_ubuntu-software.desktop[3749]: /snap/snap-store/1113/usr/bin/snap-store: symbol lookup error: /snap/snap-store/current/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gnome-software/libgnomesoftware.so.16: undefined symbol: g_task_set_static_name

I have tried the suggestion found here, namely the following:
snap refresh snap-store --beta --ignore-running

and the suggestion found here, i.e.:
snap remove snap-store
snap install snap-store --candidate

but to no avail.
Any ideas on how to resolve this?
Also, any idea why these undefined symbols keep creeping up? Surely, Canonical should have dealt with this by now... right?

No one is going to follow all those links. Include the info in your question.

"Surely, Canonical should have dealt with this by now... right?" Most people are not encountering this issue.

Do your logs have any clues after a failed attempt to start snap-store?

I can't tell if this has been 'solved'. To fix snap-store launch failure, go 'Settings' - 'Applications' - 'Snap-Store' and disable/turn OFF openGL (This works for 'Firmware-Updater' also).You may need to log-out and login back in to see change.
